# GPS Undesired Offset in MapFragment

Tags: android, gps, location, maps

I have a google map fragment set up in my activity and an onLocationChanged() and getLastKnownLocation running in coherence with it.

However when i run my application , my map points to the right city and everything but the location is off from the original location by about a few km or so .

To understand why this was happening ,

I tried the following
1. Used the Button to reset the location with the location update
2. Logged my Location
3. Waited for the interval to reset my location

In all these cases my actual location was the end result either in the map or in the log with no significance of the fake location anywhere in the log .

So i set up a camera changed listener to understand the new location and acquire the coordinates but the coordinates it gave had a much higher precision than the original coordinates and im guessing somehow the problem arises when the coordinates are parametrised into the latlng class.

Ex:

Normal:

xx.xxxxxxx xx.xxxxxxx

Camera Changed Listener coordinates:

xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx xx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Ideally you should should share the relevant code i.e. how you are getting the location. I didn't really understand and there's no point guessing. Anyway the less precise vs. more precise location is easily explained if you initially receive a location determined using the cell towers (the mobile phone network) and with some delay you then receive a "proper" GPS based location update. The network based is more like a rough estimate and can vary hundreds of meters from the more accurate GPS based location.

Comment: Both are GPS based

Comment: The problem is if I am at a given location somehow when I assign the coordinates to a marker , it gets offset . But this happens only on the first launch , even though the consequent updates maybe more or less the same location it doesn't make sense why

Comment: With a confusing problem like this, I think it would be best to show relevant code with log entries, and then show the log output, and explain why it wasn't what you expected.